# how to move cursor back in c console?

Tags: c, terminal

If I printed say 10 lines in the console, then if we want to modify the second line(or move the cursor to the second line), how to do this in C? Is there any escape sequence for that, or any method to move cursor to desired coordinates?

Comment: The C language itself has no knowledge of consoles or terminals.  POSIX does know about terminals, but it does not define specific escape sequences for terminal control, and in fact there have historically been a rather large number of terminal types with distinct control code sets.  If you want a text-based interface that supports moving the cursor around the screen, then you should look into the various external libraries that support it.  One of the most widely used is (n)curses.

Comment: Chances are that this works: `Esc` `[` row_number `;` column_number `H`. (Numbers are plain ascii representation). As stated in the comment above, it could not work...

Comment: which OS are you using.?

Comment: @anoopknr zorin(ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the cursor in a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025599/move-the-cursor-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANSI escape sequences to manipulate the screen (including the cursor position)

[ANSI-Escape-Sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) lists many of the ANSI escape sequences.

[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) page is a wiki article on the same subject