# Moving cursor in the terminal output C language

Tags: c, linux, terminal, output, character

Currently I discovered that I can move the cursor in the terminal output as if I'm writing in Word using "\033[A" to move the cursor in the line above and "\033[B" to below .
So I tried to understand something more and I wrote these 2 lines of code in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (){
printf("\n 2 3 \033[A \033[D 1 \033[B \n 4 5 6");
}
```

And this is the output :

```
      1 
 2 3
 4 5 6
```

My expectations were differents because this was my expected output

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

So I'm missing some informations and I think that probably I need of a character that says "go back of one positions" like "\t" but the opposite. I found this page in some old posts [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Input-Translation.html)

But some characters don't work.
Can someone explain me how these stuffs work? Because I tried "\033[C" and "\033[D" to move right and left but nothing.

Comment: The [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table may help to identify some of the characters you are looking for.  `\b` ( binary `10`, octal `\010`) is backspace for example.  I ran your exact code by the way and got something a little different.

Comment: Does this [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025599/move-the-cursor-in-a-c-program/33316428) help?  (you may not like the answers.)

Comment: Nice technical reference [VT100 User Guide](https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html)

Answer (score 3):

These sequences are called ANSI Escape Sequences, and date back to the 1970s with the DEC VT-100 terminal, so they're still sometimes called VT-100 escape sequences.
There's a list [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) and [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

The codes you're interested in are:

```
Esc[ValueA  Move cursor up n lines  CUU
Esc[ValueB  Move cursor down n lines    CUD
Esc[ValueC  Move cursor right n lines   CUF
Esc[ValueD  Move cursor left n lines    CUB
```

One thing you may not be accounting for is that these motions don't care "how much information" is on a given line; they just treat the screen as a grid of characters. So ESC[A goes straight up one line, even if it's "past the end" of the previous line. And so on.

So to move up one line and left two characters:

```c
printf("\033[A\033[2D");
```

`\033` is the ASCII code for ESC (in octal -- sometimes you'll see it in hex as `\x1b`; same thing). Don't add any extra spaces or newlines; just print the codes directly.

Comment: Interesting - Can you put a simple `printf` line in your answer to show exactly how that would look to say move the cursor up, and to the left?

Comment: Do you know How can I use these values in C language? I mean like printf("... ESC...") ?

Comment: Added an example. Hope that's helpful!

Comment: feel free to mark my answer as correct if you think it is. Thanks!